# Raspberry Pi NoIR camera hangs

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

**Background Information:**

I built a smart door solution with a RPi B+ (Raspbian) which makes use of three sensors (PIR, Gyroscope [I2C] and an Ultrasound). Depending on the sensor status managed by a Python script,  I start recording a video by using the raspivid command and/or play sounds on Bluetooth speakers. I also have a USB WIFI dongle connected to the RPi.

This is how I call the Pi NoIR camera in my .sh file:

```
raspivid -w 800 -h 600 -t 15000 -o file.h264 -n -rot 270
```

**Problem description:**

The camera works fine for a while (I cannot precise for how long [2 hours maybe] nor what triggers the issue), but then it stops working. The funny thing is that I get no error message.

**What did I do to identify the root cause:**

- I tried to manually kill the child process (Raspivid) but it simply doesn't work. If I kill the parent process (.sh file) then my child process gets assigned to the PID 1 (init.d).
- I tried recording a new video in a new terminal window but the new process hangs too.
- Rebooting the Pi doesn't work neither. It says it is rebooting but it does not (not even with the -f option).
- I installed a new Pi Camera ensuring it was not a hardware or ribbon problem.
- Camera has enough memory available.
- Pi has enough power (Red led is always on)
- -v returns no error
- I have installed V4L2-CTL but I have the same issue

How can I get it fixed?
Thanks!

** Edit **

dmesg:

```
[   90.555578] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   90.555698] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 3593 at drivers/media/v4l2-core/videobuf2-core.c:2135 __vb2_queue_cancel+0xf4/0x160 [videobuf2_core]()
[   90.555715] Modules linked in: evdev uinput rfcomm bnep bcm2835_v4l2 videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd spi_bcm2708 i2c_bcm2708 i2c_dev ecb btusb 8192cu bluetooth rfkill uio_pdrv_genirq uio
[   90.555843] CPU: 0 PID: 3593 Comm: v4l2-ctl Not tainted 3.18.7+ #755
[   90.555915] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[   90.556012] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
[   90.556053] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0022ef4>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x7c/0x9c)
[   90.556083] [<c0022ef4>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c0022fd0>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x2c/0x34)
[   90.556143] [<c0022fd0>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<bf263a1c>] (__vb2_queue_cancel+0xf4/0x160 [videobuf2_core])
[   90.556252] [<bf263a1c>] (__vb2_queue_cancel [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf265548>] (vb2_internal_streamoff+0x40/0xdc [videobuf2_core])
[   90.556361] [<bf265548>] (vb2_internal_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf2656d8>] (vb2_streamoff+0x3c/0x60 [videobuf2_core])
[   90.556436] [<bf2656d8>] (vb2_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf26574c>] (vb2_ioctl_streamoff+0x50/0x54 [videobuf2_core])
[   90.556669] [<bf26574c>] (vb2_ioctl_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf228658>] (v4l_streamoff+0x28/0x2c [videodev])
[   90.556938] [<bf228658>] (v4l_streamoff [videodev]) from [<bf22baf4>] (__video_do_ioctl+0x254/0x2e8 [videodev])
[   90.557182] [<bf22baf4>] (__video_do_ioctl [videodev]) from [<bf22b49c>] (video_usercopy+0x180/0x560 [videodev])
[   90.557414] [<bf22b49c>] (video_usercopy [videodev]) from [<bf22b898>] (video_ioctl2+0x1c/0x24 [videodev])
[   90.557616] [<bf22b898>] (video_ioctl2 [videodev]) from [<bf2266b0>] (v4l2_ioctl+0x11c/0x14c [videodev])
[   90.557791] [<bf2266b0>] (v4l2_ioctl [videodev]) from [<c014c478>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x3f0/0x5d4)
[   90.557872] [<c014c478>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<c014c6a0>] (SyS_ioctl+0x44/0x6c)
[   90.557917] [<c014c6a0>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<c000e8c0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
[   90.557936] ---[ end trace 28c9150399e29093 ]---
[ 3123.544118] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 3123.544235] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 28629 at drivers/media/v4l2-core/videobuf2-core.c:2135 __vb2_queue_cancel+0xf4/0x160 [videobuf2_core]()
[ 3123.544251] Modules linked in: evdev uinput rfcomm bnep bcm2835_v4l2 videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd spi_bcm2708 i2c_bcm2708 i2c_dev ecb btusb 8192cu bluetooth rfkill uio_pdrv_genirq uio
[ 3123.544404] CPU: 0 PID: 28629 Comm: v4l2-ctl Tainted: G        W      3.18.7+ #755
[ 3123.544475] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[ 3123.544570] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
[ 3123.544676] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0022ef4>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x7c/0x9c)
[ 3123.545092] [<c0022ef4>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c0022fd0>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x2c/0x34)
[ 3123.545178] [<c0022fd0>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<bf263a1c>] (__vb2_queue_cancel+0xf4/0x160 [videobuf2_core])
[ 3123.545253] [<bf263a1c>] (__vb2_queue_cancel [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf265548>] (vb2_internal_streamoff+0x40/0xdc [videobuf2_core])
[ 3123.545316] [<bf265548>] (vb2_internal_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf2656d8>] (vb2_streamoff+0x3c/0x60 [videobuf2_core])
[ 3123.545377] [<bf2656d8>] (vb2_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf26574c>] (vb2_ioctl_streamoff+0x50/0x54 [videobuf2_core])
[ 3123.545562] [<bf26574c>] (vb2_ioctl_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf228658>] (v4l_streamoff+0x28/0x2c [videodev])
[ 3123.545803] [<bf228658>] (v4l_streamoff [videodev]) from [<bf22baf4>] (__video_do_ioctl+0x254/0x2e8 [videodev])
[ 3123.546060] [<bf22baf4>] (__video_do_ioctl [videodev]) from [<bf22b49c>] (video_usercopy+0x180/0x560 [videodev])
[ 3123.546309] [<bf22b49c>] (video_usercopy [videodev]) from [<bf22b898>] (video_ioctl2+0x1c/0x24 [videodev])
[ 3123.546483] [<bf22b898>] (video_ioctl2 [videodev]) from [<bf2266b0>] (v4l2_ioctl+0x11c/0x14c [videodev])
[ 3123.546595] [<bf2266b0>] (v4l2_ioctl [videodev]) from [<c014c478>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x3f0/0x5d4)
[ 3123.546676] [<c014c478>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<c014c6a0>] (SyS_ioctl+0x44/0x6c)
[ 3123.546717] [<c014c6a0>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<c000e8c0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
[ 3123.546737] ---[ end trace 28c9150399e29094 ]---
[34462.831249] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[34465.833783] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[34465.833853] bcm2835_v4l2: failed disconnecting src port
[34468.833772] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[34468.833818] bcm2835-v4l2: Failed to disable encode component -62
[34471.834219] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[34471.834395] bcm2835-v4l2: vidioc_s_fmt_vid_cap: failed to setup mmal components: -62
[34474.873813] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[34474.890435] bcm2835-v4l2: queue_setup: capture port not configured
[34495.914162] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[34498.916190] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[34498.916290] bcm2835-v4l2: vidioc_s_fmt_vid_cap: failed to setup mmal components: -62
[34502.064159] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[34502.070076] bcm2835-v4l2: queue_setup: capture port not configured
[36016.330148] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[36019.339279] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[36019.339327] bcm2835-v4l2: vidioc_s_fmt_vid_cap: failed to setup mmal components: -62
[36022.430218] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
[36022.441684] bcm2835-v4l2: queue_setup: capture port not configured
```

syslog:

```
Feb 20 05:35:02 raspberrypi kernel: [34462.831249] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 05:35:05 raspberrypi kernel: [34465.833783] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 05:35:05 raspberrypi kernel: [34465.833853] bcm2835_v4l2: failed disconnecting src port
Feb 20 05:35:08 raspberrypi kernel: [34468.833772] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 05:35:08 raspberrypi kernel: [34468.833818] bcm2835-v4l2: Failed to disable encode component -62
Feb 20 05:35:11 raspberrypi kernel: [34471.834219] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 05:35:11 raspberrypi kernel: [34471.834395] bcm2835-v4l2: vidioc_s_fmt_vid_cap: failed to setup mmal components: -62
Feb 20 05:35:14 raspberrypi kernel: [34474.873813] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 05:35:14 raspberrypi kernel: [34474.890435] bcm2835-v4l2: queue_setup: capture port not configured
Feb 20 05:35:35 raspberrypi kernel: [34495.914162] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 05:35:38 raspberrypi kernel: [34498.916190] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 05:35:38 raspberrypi kernel: [34498.916290] bcm2835-v4l2: vidioc_s_fmt_vid_cap: failed to setup mmal components: -62
Feb 20 05:35:41 raspberrypi kernel: [34502.064159] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 05:35:41 raspberrypi kernel: [34502.070076] bcm2835-v4l2: queue_setup: capture port not configured
Feb 20 06:00:55 raspberrypi kernel: [36016.330148] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 06:00:58 raspberrypi kernel: [36019.339279] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 06:00:58 raspberrypi kernel: [36019.339327] bcm2835-v4l2: vidioc_s_fmt_vid_cap: failed to setup mmal components: -62
Feb 20 06:01:01 raspberrypi kernel: [36022.430218] bcm2835_v4l2: error 0 waiting for sync completion
Feb 20 06:01:01 raspberrypi kernel: [36022.441684] bcm2835-v4l2: queue_setup: capture port not configured
```

messages:

```
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.555578] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.555698] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 3593 at drivers/media/v4l2-core/videobuf2-core.c:2135 __vb2_queue_cancel+0xf4/0x160 [videobuf2_core]()
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.555715] Modules linked in: evdev uinput rfcomm bnep bcm2835_v4l2 videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd spi_bcm2708 i2c_bcm2708 i2c_dev ecb btusb 8192cu bluetooth rfkill uio_pdrv_genirq uio
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.555843] CPU: 0 PID: 3593 Comm: v4l2-ctl Not tainted 3.18.7+ #755
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.555915] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.556012] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.556053] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0022ef4>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x7c/0x9c)
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.556083] [<c0022ef4>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c0022fd0>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x2c/0x34)
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.556143] [<c0022fd0>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<bf263a1c>] (__vb2_queue_cancel+0xf4/0x160 [videobuf2_core])
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.556252] [<bf263a1c>] (__vb2_queue_cancel [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf265548>] (vb2_internal_streamoff+0x40/0xdc [videobuf2_core])
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.556361] [<bf265548>] (vb2_internal_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf2656d8>] (vb2_streamoff+0x3c/0x60 [videobuf2_core])
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.556436] [<bf2656d8>] (vb2_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf26574c>] (vb2_ioctl_streamoff+0x50/0x54 [videobuf2_core])
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.556669] [<bf26574c>] (vb2_ioctl_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf228658>] (v4l_streamoff+0x28/0x2c [videodev])
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.556938] [<bf228658>] (v4l_streamoff [videodev]) from [<bf22baf4>] (__video_do_ioctl+0x254/0x2e8 [videodev])
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.557182] [<bf22baf4>] (__video_do_ioctl [videodev]) from [<bf22b49c>] (video_usercopy+0x180/0x560 [videodev])
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.557414] [<bf22b49c>] (video_usercopy [videodev]) from [<bf22b898>] (video_ioctl2+0x1c/0x24 [videodev])
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.557616] [<bf22b898>] (video_ioctl2 [videodev]) from [<bf2266b0>] (v4l2_ioctl+0x11c/0x14c [videodev])
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.557791] [<bf2266b0>] (v4l2_ioctl [videodev]) from [<c014c478>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x3f0/0x5d4)
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.557872] [<c014c478>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<c014c6a0>] (SyS_ioctl+0x44/0x6c)
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.557917] [<c014c6a0>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<c000e8c0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
Feb 19 20:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.557936] ---[ end trace 28c9150399e29093 ]---
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.544118] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.544235] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 28629 at drivers/media/v4l2-core/videobuf2-core.c:2135 __vb2_queue_cancel+0xf4/0x160 [videobuf2_core]()
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.544251] Modules linked in: evdev uinput rfcomm bnep bcm2835_v4l2 videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd spi_bcm2708 i2c_bcm2708 i2c_dev ecb btusb 8192cu bluetooth rfkill uio_pdrv_genirq uio
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.544404] CPU: 0 PID: 28629 Comm: v4l2-ctl Tainted: G        W      3.18.7+ #755
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.544475] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.544570] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.544676] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0022ef4>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x7c/0x9c)
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.545092] [<c0022ef4>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c0022fd0>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x2c/0x34)
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.545178] [<c0022fd0>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<bf263a1c>] (__vb2_queue_cancel+0xf4/0x160 [videobuf2_core])
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.545253] [<bf263a1c>] (__vb2_queue_cancel [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf265548>] (vb2_internal_streamoff+0x40/0xdc [videobuf2_core])
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.545316] [<bf265548>] (vb2_internal_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf2656d8>] (vb2_streamoff+0x3c/0x60 [videobuf2_core])
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.545377] [<bf2656d8>] (vb2_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf26574c>] (vb2_ioctl_streamoff+0x50/0x54 [videobuf2_core])
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.545562] [<bf26574c>] (vb2_ioctl_streamoff [videobuf2_core]) from [<bf228658>] (v4l_streamoff+0x28/0x2c [videodev])
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.545803] [<bf228658>] (v4l_streamoff [videodev]) from [<bf22baf4>] (__video_do_ioctl+0x254/0x2e8 [videodev])
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.546060] [<bf22baf4>] (__video_do_ioctl [videodev]) from [<bf22b49c>] (video_usercopy+0x180/0x560 [videodev])
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.546309] [<bf22b49c>] (video_usercopy [videodev]) from [<bf22b898>] (video_ioctl2+0x1c/0x24 [videodev])
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.546483] [<bf22b898>] (video_ioctl2 [videodev]) from [<bf2266b0>] (v4l2_ioctl+0x11c/0x14c [videodev])
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.546595] [<bf2266b0>] (v4l2_ioctl [videodev]) from [<c014c478>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x3f0/0x5d4)
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.546676] [<c014c478>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<c014c6a0>] (SyS_ioctl+0x44/0x6c)
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.546717] [<c014c6a0>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<c000e8c0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
Feb 19 20:52:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 3123.546737] ---[ end trace 28c9150399e29094 ]---
```

Comment: No messages in `dmesg` or syslog? Does the Pi get enough power? You have quite a power hungry setup that might be prone to power fluctuations. What happens if you re-plug the camera after it fails? What's the `dmesg` output then?

Comment: There is enough power since the red led remains on all the time. Re-plugging the camera does not change anything. -v returns no errors. Which syslog are you talking about? Thank you!

Comment: `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`/ and the `dmesg` command.

Comment: Thanks again. I have just checked and no related error (at least not related to camera, raspivid or the driver name). Any keywork? Should I post it here?

Comment: Just after the lockup happens, see what `dmesg` tells you. The last few (~10) lines should be important. Maybe the driver fails and tells you.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the `bcm2835_v4l2` kernel module. Try reloading it: `rmmod bcm2835_v4l2; modprobe bcm2835_v4l2`.

Comment: I will test and let you know. Camera is actually working fine because I have just restarted :-) . If it works, please post your answer so I reward you with the bounty. Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi nemo. That doesn't seem to solve the issue. Reloading the module doesn't let me record new videos unless I physically reboot my Pi. The process which has the raspivid cannot be killed. If I kill its parent then I gets assigned to the PID 1. I am out of hope I can get this issue fixed.

Comment: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:753 kmod_module_remove_module: could not remove 'bcm2835_v4l2': Device or resource busy
Error: could not remove module bcm2835_v4l2: Device or resource busy

Comment: Hi @KagueiNakueka I browsed here after seeing the bounty bacuase I've had a streaming camera working on a Pi (although external USB webcam, not the Pi Cam). I see that you have deleted an answer referring to I2C conflict with another device.  Does that mean that it **was** the root cause, but you still need to use the camera with the other device attached to the same Pi?  Or does it mean that disconnecting the other device did not, in fact, solve the problem?  Can you edit that information into the question?

Comment: I would not rely on the red LED to signify that power is sufficient. All it takes is one little glitch to mess things up.

Comment: your problem seems to stem from the V4L2 driver, there's a pretty active forum on the raspberry Pi site - see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=62364&hilit=bcm2835_v4l2%3A+error+0+waiting+for+sync+completion&start=375).  Your problem seems to resemble a few of those reported there - definitely worth checking you've got the latest patches talked about there.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your kernel messages, specifically the line containing '__vb2_queue_cancel', I think your problem may partially be related to Raspberry's kernel drivers. Have you checked if your kernel contains the fix given at [1]? If not, applying that oneliner may fix your problem.

For some reason your camera application is stopping video capture and due to the aformentioned bug it fails to do so. This may at least give you a chance to restart your capture pipeline.

[1] https://github.com/6by9/linux/commit/f1e870c2c910d0620b1a48ac7165c8f9e9a75527